# myTv+ app returns error code 101 when running on Android TV box

Tags: applications, android-tv

I have installed an IP TV app, myTv+ (https://mytv-plus.com/mytvws/) on my Huawei smartphone and it worked fine.

I tried to install it on the Android TV box (MXQ Pro 4K), but it's simply not working, just getting error code 101. It appears when running the app. The install just goes smoothly, but the code appears on the splash screen.

I contacted the developer and he said this app is designed only for the smartphone.

Is there any way I can force the app to work with the Android TV box?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the decompiled code there is some error method that is called with 101. It looks like this code is only executed when the parameters sent to the app on startup are not as the app expects:

On Android TV apps are started using a different "parameter" (`android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER`) where as a regular Android app is started via `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`.

I have not checked it in detail but it looks like the app tries to process the parameters and fails as it does not understand the parameter used by Android TV and then displays the 101 error message.